# Unable to add clusters in Argo CD

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, cd, argocd

I have an eks cluster(Argo cd cluster) and Argo CD running on that and i want to add the another EKS Cluster(staging) which is on another AWS Account, while adding the cluster with argocd cli i'm getting the below error

argocd cluster add

`FATA[0034] rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = Get "https://7676334634763764377B080FC2E502754A3.gr7.eu-central-1.eks.amazonaws.com/version?timeout=32s": dial tcp 52.87.96.207:443: i/o timeout`

My staging cluster public access is restricted to office VPN, i have whitelisted the NAT Ip and ingress controller IP also of Argocd cluster still Im getting the error.

PS: When disable the public access cidr access then i'm able to add the cluster successfully.

Not sure what i'm missing here anyone can help me out here.

Comment: Answer : I'm able to figure it out just need to whitelist the NAT IP of argocd cluster, i was updated the wrong IP

Comment: Tangentially related, both clusters reside in the same VPC. Problem I was running into is that the argo server was trying to connect to the remote cluster via the control plane's internal address (cluster is using both public & private endpoints). This is because a dig/nslookup from within the cluster gives the internal address of the control plane not the publicly accessible endpoint. The security group of the Argo server must be allowed by the security group of the remote cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on your answer, you would need to:

- Identifying the Correct NAT IP of the Argo CD cluster, using [AWS NAT Gateways](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html):

  ```bash
  # Use AWS CLI to describe the NAT Gateway and find the correct NAT IP
  aws ec2 describe-nat-gateways --query 'NatGateways[?VpcId==`<vpc-id>`].{NatGatewayAddresses: NatGatewayAddresses}'
  ```
- Updating the Whitelist on the new EKS cluster to include this IP ([security group settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-security-groups.html)):

  ```bash
  # That would likely be done in the AWS Management Console, under the security group settings for the new EKS cluster
  # Alternatively, it can be done using the AWS CLI or SDKs
  aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id <security-group-id> --protocol tcp --port 443 --cidr <nat-ip>/32
  ```

[image: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/images/vpc/latest/userguide/images/security-group-overview.png]

- Test the Connection, using the [`argocd cluster add` command](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/commands/argocd_cluster_add/).

  ```bash
  argocd cluster add <staging-cluster>
  ```

The correct NAT IP should be whitelisted, allowing the Argo CD instance to communicate with the new EKS cluster and resolving the timeout error.

```bash
+--------------------+         +---------------------+          +---------------------+
| Argo CD Cluster    |         |  AWS NAT Gateway    |          | Staging EKS Cluster |
| (eks-cluster-argo) |         |    (Correct NAT IP) |          | (staging-cluster)   |
|                    |         |                     |          |                     |
| ArgoCD Instance    | <-----> | Whitelisted NAT IP  | <------> | Allowed Access      |
|                    |         |                     |          | (Office VPN)        |
+--------------------+         +---------------------+          +---------------------+
```